# React Ionic Modal not closing when button clicked

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I used the Ionic docs' guide on using boolean state to determine when to open or close my modal.
When card is clicked, it sets state to open the modal, but when the close icon is pressed it does not change the state back to false or close the modal.
Would it be possible if I created a separate component to handle this behaviour?

```
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  IonCard,
  IonGrid,
  IonCardHeader,
  IonCardTitle,
  IonCardSubtitle,
  IonText,
  IonCardContent,
  IonImg,
  IonRow,
  IonCol,
  IonAvatar,
  IonModal,
  IonHeader,
  IonToolbar,
  IonIcon,
  IonTitle,
} from "@ionic/react";
import { closeOutline, closeSharp } from "ionicons/icons";

import "./UserCard.css";

type UserCardProps = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  icon: string;
  email: string;
  country: string;
  image: string;
  description: string;
};

export const UserCard = (props: UserCardProps) => {
  const [detailModal, setDetailModal] = useState({ isOpen: false });

  const handleClose = () => {
    console.log(`Value before setDetailModal: ${detailModal.isOpen}`);
    setDetailModal({ isOpen: false });
    console.log(`Value after setDetailModal: ${detailModal.isOpen}`);
  };
  return (
    <IonCard
      onClick={() => setDetailModal({ isOpen: true })}
      id={`${props.name}Modal`}
    >
      {/* When card clicked, open modal */}
      <IonModal isOpen={detailModal.isOpen}>
        <IonHeader>
          <IonToolbar mode="ios" className="ion-padding">
            <IonIcon
              slot="start"
              ios={closeOutline}
              md={closeSharp}
              onClick={handleClose} // Modal currently does not close when clicked
            />
            <IonTitle className="ionTextCenter">{props.name}</IonTitle>
          </IonToolbar>
        </IonHeader>

        {/* Detailed Modal component */}
        <IonCard id="detailModal">
          <IonCardHeader>
            <IonImg src={props.image} />
            <IonGrid>
              <IonRow>
                <IonCol size="3">
                  <IonAvatar>
                    <img src={props.icon} />
                  </IonAvatar>
                </IonCol>
                <IonCol size="9">
                  <IonCardTitle>{props.name}</IonCardTitle>
                  <IonCardSubtitle>{props.email}</IonCardSubtitle>
                </IonCol>
              </IonRow>
            </IonGrid>
          </IonCardHeader>
          <IonCardContent>
            <IonText>
              <p>This photo was taken in: {props.country}</p>
            </IonText>
          </IonCardContent>
        </IonCard>
      </IonModal>
      {/* Detailed Modal component end */}

      {/* Card component */}
      <IonCardHeader className="card-header">
        <IonGrid>
          <IonRow>
            <IonCol size="3">
              <IonAvatar>
                <img src={props.icon} />
              </IonAvatar>
            </IonCol>
            <IonCol size="9">
              <IonCardTitle>{props.name}</IonCardTitle>
              <IonCardSubtitle>{props.email}</IonCardSubtitle>
            </IonCol>
          </IonRow>
        </IonGrid>
      </IonCardHeader>
      <IonCardContent>
        <img src={props.image} className="center-img" />
        <IonText className="ion-text-center ion-margin">
          <h2 className="subheading">{props.country}</h2>
        </IonText>
        <IonImg className="character-img"></IonImg>
        {props.description}
      </IonCardContent>
      {/* Card component end */}
    </IonCard>
  );
};
```

Comment: Did you find what is causing this issue? I am having a similar issue. It works fine for other modals, but another one is broken somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use an arrow function with handle close?

Check out
https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

```
<IonIcon
              slot="start"
              ios={closeOutline}
              md={closeSharp}
              onClick={() => handleClose()} 
            />
```

Check out this link too!
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: Thanks! Will checkout the links, but unfortunately arrow function did not solve the issue

Comment: Could you also try removing the object from your state and setting it to just true or false? Maybe there's an issue with the state accessing the object properties?

`
const [detailModal, setDetailModal] = useState(false);
```
and
 ```
const handleClose = () => {
    console.log(`Value before setDetailModal: ${detailModal.isOpen}`);
    setDetailModal(false);
    console.log(`Value after setDetailModal: ${detailModal.isOpen}`);
  };
`

Comment: Created a local boolean and it didn't open or close upon clicking the card. Likely because detailModal's state needs to be managed to prompt the Modal without refreshing the page.